VSCode Extension Debugger SetVariableRequest is never called
    protected setVariableRequest(
    response: DebugProtocol.SetVariableResponse,
    args: DebugProtocol.SetVariableArguments): void {
    this.outputChannel.appendLine("setVariableRequest");
    console.log(args);

My setVariableRequest is never called. All my other requests works but just this one I don't know what's wrong with it.
I have this in my initializeRequest.
esponse.body.supportsSetVariable = true;
I did this, it succesfully turn into an input field, but it doesn't allow me to update the value.
enter image description here
I have no idea where do I event start to debug this.
